# Implement AutoShutDown with timers

Tags: .net, winforms

I want to implement an auto shutdown feature when my application hasn't work to do.
I use three System.WindowForm.Timer

```
     private void mainTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)  //mainTimer 1 sec period
    {
        doWork();
        .....
        if(noItems && checkBoxShutDow.Checked)
            this.Autoshutdown();
    }
```

In AutoshutDown I display a Form after 5 sec and starts counting 59,58 ... 0 unless I press Cancel.
If I press Cancel then unchecks checkBoxShutDow and the ShutDown is aborted.

```
    bool autoshutStarted;
    private void Autoshutdown()
    {
        var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Enabled = true, Interval = 5000 };
        timer.Tick += delegate
        {
            if(!checkBoxShutDow.Checked)
               return;
            autoshutStarted = true;
            AutoCloseFrm frm = new AutoCloseFrm();
            if(frm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
              Process.Start("ShutDown", "/s"); 
            else
                checkBoxShutDow.Checked=false;
            autoshutStarted = false;
            timer.Dispose();
        };
    }
```

AutoCloseFrm is a modal form that displays the message every second, and returns DialogResult.OK when counter=60. It has a Cancel button that returns DialogResult.Cancel if I want to Abort.

```
   private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        sec++;
        lblShutMsg.Text = "Automatic Shutdown in " + (60 - sec) + " seconds";
        if(sec >= 60) DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

The problem is sometimes I press cancel and another form is displayed.

Comment: What "other" form is displayed???  Pretty unusual have to such unruly forms.

Comment: Sorry "AutoCloseFrm" is displayed again when I press Cancel. I tried autoshutStarted bool to prevent multiple

Comment: Sure, but you actually check it.  Just stop that timer before you display the dialog.

Comment: I removed the timer from Autoshutdown() and  I added a timeToDisplay counter to the main timer  if(noItems && checkBoxShutDow.Checked && timeTodisplay++ >=5)